# Заанимировать движение элемента

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, html

Мне нужно создать что-то вроде шкалы с несколькими точками, по которым можно передвигать ползунок.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="point point-1"></div>
  <div class="point point-2"></div>
  <div class="point point-3"></div>
  <div class="point point-4"></div>
  <div class="toddler"></div>
</div>
```

**Скрипт**

```
$.fn.slider = function () {
var startCoord = $(this).offset().left;
var endCoord = startCoord + $(this).width();

/*console.log(startCoord);
console.log(endCoord);*/

var points = $(this).find(".point");
var len = points.length;
/*console.log(len);*/

var pointsCoordsX = [];
var i = 0;

for (i = 0; i != len; i++) {
    var coord = points.eq(i).offset().left;
    /*console.log(coord);*/
    pointsCoordsX.push(coord);
}

var toddler = $(this).find(".toddler");
toddler.bind('mousedown', function (e) {
    var toddlerW = toddler.width();
    var toddlerH = toddler.height();
    var toddlerX = toddler.offset().left;
    /*console.log(toddlerX);*/

    $(this).bind('mousemove', function (e) {
        var x = (e.pageX - toddlerX - (toddlerW / 2)) * (toddlerW > toddlerH ? (toddlerH / toddlerW) : 1);
        /*console.log(x);*/
        var PrevPointX;
        var NextPointX;
        for (i = 0; i != len - 1; i++) {
            if (toddlerX >= pointsCoordsX[i] && toddlerX <= pointsCoordsX[i + 1]) {
                PrevPointX = pointsCoordsX[i];
                NextPointX = pointsCoordsX[i + 1];
            }
        }
        /*console.log(PrevPointX);
        console.log(NextPointX);*/
        if (x > 0) {
            var diffX1 = NextPointX - toddlerX;
            /*console.log(diffX);*/
            $(this).animate({'right': + '+=' + diffX1});
        }
        else {
            var diffX2 = toddlerX - PrevPointX;
            /*console.log(diffX);*/
            $(this).animate({'left': + '+=' + diffX2});
        }
    });
});
};


$(".wrapper").slider();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vvxnb0u9/60/

Не могу разобраться, почему не работает анимация?
И как запретить двигать ползунок во время анимации, чтобы он сначала дошел до точки и чтобы только после этого его можно было снова шевелить?

Comment: Все уже придумано до нас: http://jqueryui.com/slider/

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить

```
$(this).animate({'right': + '+=' + diffX1});
```

на

```
$(this).animate({right:'+=' + diffX1});
```